# AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout - shrink content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have AppBarLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout. Inside I have an ImageView as a background, and  ConstraintLayout with TextViews. Expected behaviour on scroll: the AppBarLayout shrinks just enough so that the the whole ConstraintLayout is still visible. Unfortunately what happens for me, is that the ConstraintLayout moves up and is out of view.

Here's what I want it to look like:

**Before scroll**

[image: Before scroll]

**after scroll**

[image: After scroll]

Instead, this is what I have right now:

**Before scroll**

[image: Before scroll]

**After scroll**

[image: After scroll]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="262dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="#00FFFFFF"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:src="@drawable/img_dashboard"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/featured_main_text"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Offline"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="2 hrs ago"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/featured_main_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="John Smith"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="28dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Place Holder"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="28dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Place Holder"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="28dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I looked at CollapsingToolbarLayout tutorials, but can't find anything where it just shrinks instead of actually collapsing into a toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

All what you have written in your code will not work out of box. If you want to achieve the result how it shows in your expected screenshot you need to write `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` for each View/viewGroup that hold your items. And set it to your View/ViewGroup.